# gradients 2 variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $\phi$ , so that $F(x,y)=\nabla \phi (x,y)$

When $F(x,y)=(y\cos x, \sin x +\frac{2y}{3} e^{y^2})$ and when

$F(x,y)=(\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{2x}{1+x^2 y}, \frac{1}{xy}+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2 y})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to solve for $\partial \phi/\partial x=F_1$, $\partial \phi/\partial y=F_2$. So for the first case
\begin{equation}
\partial \phi/\partial x=y \cos(x) \Rightarrow \phi=y\sin(x)+f(y)
\end{equation}
recall that the indefinite integral of a function of one variable is determined up to a constant. For a funciton of two variables, the integral with respect to one of the variables is determined up to a function of the other variable, which in this case I called $f$. We find $f$ by imposing the other condition:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial \phi/\partial y&= \sin x+(2/3)y\exp(y^2)\\
\sin(x)+f^\prime(y)&= \sin x+(2/3)y\exp(y^2)\\
\Rightarrow f(y)=(1/3)\exp(y^2)+c
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Therefore $\phi=y\sin(x)+(1/3)\exp(y^2)+c$.